# Folders from Windows server no longer accessible after setting a static IP for the server

Tags: windows-10, home-networking, shared-folders

I share multiple folders from my Windows system on a local home network and it has been working fine.  I recently changed the Windows server to use a static IP address and other clients in the network cannot access shares they previously could.

The error I receive is network path not found, and whenever I click on the server's name under network on explorer it says Windows cannon access it.

Before, with DHCP, everything worked fine; all the folders I had shared with all the users worked just fine.  But now that I have added a static IP address for my home server the folder sharing doesn't work anymore,  How can I solve this?

My Windows 10 system is running up to date.

The only thing I changed prior to breaking everything was adding a static IP address, so I assumed all the discovery settings would work the same.

I'm able to access the system via Remote Desktop using the computer's name, Plex works fine, and Internet on the server works very well.

Comment: Do you access shared files by host name or IP? Is this static IP the same as the IP assigned by DHCP before?

Access by IP: That may be a problem with your network configuration. Then you need to check the network configuration.

Access by host name: It may be a problem with DNS resolution. If the static IP is different from the IP assigned by the previous DHCP, try to clear the cache and add the new IP to the DNS zone file.

Comment: Hi S.Leon, I was using the host name, it's been working for years, dont think it has the same IP as the DHCP, I assigned outside of the DHCP range set by the modem. Last night I did try to go back to DHCP to test and folder sharing along with trying to access via the host name didnt work at all. Possibly I have to change my folder sharing to be via the IP directly ?

Comment: Try if you can successfully ping this server.

Comment: I can, I was trying that right now I can successfully ping it and tracert to it

Comment: Try to change your folder sharing via IP.

Answer (score 0):

And it should work, the only think make me doubt is that you say you are able to connect on the host name with RDP (plex discovering the service probably on broadcast address, so it should work also without DNS). Had you try to clean the cache of dns on your computer? Do an ipconfig /flushdns and restart computer, this will clear the cache and later you can try to connect again via RDP. Anyway you can try out to check on the router if an entry for the server name exist or not, also check the workgroup name, have to be the same for all computer and (maybe) it was until your dhcp distribute it.

Another way fix your issue is to put back the server in DHCP mode and create a dhcp reservation for it.

Comment: Thanks for the post AtomiX84, I had forgotten about the workgroups, but they do match :(
Flushing the dns didn't work either, I may have to go back to DHCP :(

Comment: I'm sorry that does not work, if you ping and try to resolve the name with nslookup they works? Not sure but may also can help a tcp/ip protocol reset https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility